# Error code 1055 on Expression #3 – because of duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql

I need help explaining why I get Error Code 1055 on Expression #3 in this code. I'm trying to figure out what player has the best goal scoring streak (i.e. goals in most games in a row). Do I get the error because the same player can occure more than once?
People.id is primary key, gamestats.gameid is unique.

[![Example of the gamestats table sctructure][1]][1]

```
SELECT
    people.id as ID,
    people.person AS PlayerName,
    @count:=IF(a.goal >= b.goal, @count + 1, 1) AS Streak
FROM
    Gamestats a
        LEFT JOIN
    Gamestats b ON a.gameID = b.gameID + 1
        LEFT JOIN
    people ON people.id = a.id
WHERE
    a.goal > 0
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY Streak DESC
LIMIT 5


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1NNH.png
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Expected output:
PLAYER - STREAK
NN - 16

16 referring to games with at least 1 goal in a row